# How to sign in into Office Pro Plus 2019 using my Microsoft account

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2019

I have a Microsoft Account which is already linked to my Windows 10. I wanted to do the same with my Microsoft Office Pro Plus 2019, but I'm not able to sign in using my Microsoft Account. The Office however is already activated.

I manage to sign in using my Gmail account, but it was months ago and I already forgot how I did it.

I tried to sign out the Gmail account or even switch account, but all I'm getting is the same issue:

Screenshot of the issue:

[image: See the screenshot of the issue]

Comment: Email seems clear, a Microsoft Account with the username of your Google email account, doesn’t exist with a license to Office.  Use “try a different account” to switch to a different Microsoft Account

Comment: As Ramhound said you could use "try a different account", if it still does not work, please make sure you have activated Office Pro Plus 2019. Go to Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\Identity\Identities, delete it after back up this key (right click it and Export). Then restart Office and try to sign in the account that you want.

Comment: If you were able to sign in with your Gmail account previously, you likely [shared](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Share-your-Office-365-Home-subscription-b389b9ce-3ae3-4a82-9017-39d79972fcba) your subscription with that email.  @EmilyHua Please place monospaced code inside code backticks _(please see help link at bottom right of comment box)_